# how to correctly split with awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I am trying to remove this :

```
2012-04-04 07:51:04 (2012-04-04 11:51:04.399000000Z): subject=PROD.
```

from the following

```
2012-04-04 07:51:04 (2012-04-04 11:51:04.399000000Z): subject=PROD.sdmp.o.t.0.0.0.0.NewOrderExecutionOE.?.4366.0.2.3.1.TNP.FIDESSA.IBAPPBAL504.EQUITY, message={PL=[10 3 49 46 51 18 3 84 78 80 26 7 70 73 68 69 83 83 65 34 37 79 69 45 50 48 49 50 48 52 48 52 45 48 48 48 48 52 54 55 55 52 48 50 84 82 83 70 49 46 49 46 49 45 48 48 50 49 42 19 78 101 119 79 114 100 101 114 69 120 101 99 117 116 105 111 110 79 69 50 128 8 10 189 4 8 240 46 16 0 24 0 48 0 56 0 64 0 72 2 80 2 88 2 96 0 104 216 29 112 0 120 174 11 128 1 2 136 1 136 165 215 226 231 38 144 1 223 3 152 1 1 160 1 246 181 215 226 231 38 168 1 223 3 176 1 0 194 1 7 70 73 68 69 83 83 65 200 1 1 210 1 37 79 69 45 50 48 49 50 48 52 48 52 45 48 48 48 48 52 54 55 55 52 48 50 84 82 83 70 49 46 49 46 49 45 48 48 50 49 218 1 78 83 85 70 73 32 83 83 32 49 57 48 48 32 83 84 68 32 64 32 55 46 50 55 32 85 83 68 32 65 67 67 79 85 78 84 32 67 83 87 69 45 73 78 86 45 78 77 77 32 67 79 78 84 82 65 32 65 82 67 65 32 83 70 71 45 67 79 82 82 69 83 80 79 78 68 69 78 84 224 1 203 85 242 1 22 67 65 82 77 69 76 79 46 82 85 66 65 78 79 64 83 85 70 73 46 85 83 248 1 30 128 2 213 11 146 2 4 83 85 70 73 152 2 5 168 2 5 176 2 1 186 2 7 16 11 26 3 85 83 68 192 2 142 34 202 2 7 16 3 26 3 83 84 68 146 3 7 70 73 68 69 83 83 65 162 3 46 79 114 100 101 114 73 110 115 116 114 117 99 116 105 111 110 45 50 48 49 50 48 52 48 52 45 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 50 49 78 79 83 70 49 45 49 45 49 170 3 7 70 73 68 69 83 83 65 186 3 24 79 114 100 101 114 45 50 48 49 50 48 52 48 52 45 50 49 78 79 83 70 49 45 49 192 3 14 202 3 15 65 114 99 97 69 120 69 120 101 99 86 101 110 117 101 208 3 8 218 3 8 78 89 83 69 65 114 99 97 232 3 213 11 250 3 4 83 85 70 73 128 4 5 136 4 203 85 154 4 22 67 65 82 77 69 76 79 46 82 85 66 65 78 79 64 83 85 70 73 46 85 83 160 4 30 168 4 213 11 186 4 4 83 85 70 73 192 4 5 208 4 210 13 226 4 7 85 78 75 78 79 87 78 240 4 85 130 5 4 65 82 67 65 136 5 5 144 5 85 162 5 4 65 82 67 65 168 5 5 184 5 137 244 17 194 5 12 67 83 87 69 45 73 78 86 45 78 77 77 202 5 4 73 66 82 75 208 5 214 188 12 218 5 17 83 70 71 45 67 79 82 82 69 83 80 79 78 68 69 78 84 226 5 4 73 66 82 75 216 6 0 226 6 2 16 0 128 7 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 58 11 73 66 65 80 80 66 65 76 53 48 52 64 207 247 148 134 237 137 184 231 8] ET[1]=2012-04-04 11:51:01Z}
```

but im not sure how to use awk or cut to do this, no matter what I do I cant get it right.
I know you have to use $i in awk, but I cant get the split right to get what I want.

any help would be appreciated.

ok, here is how I tried using cut:

```
cut -d "." -f3- data.log > dataCut.log
```

This here worked for most of the file, but at some point it cut off the sdmp., which is something I need.

Comment: **Show us what you've tried so far.**  Don't describe it, but edit the question and paste in the actual code.  Then tell us what didn't work.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `GNU grep` then simply:

```
grep -Po 'PROD[.]\K.*' file
```

Comment: I think you inverted the answer which was to *delete* the string you're matching

Comment: @FredrikPihl I'm glad somebody is paying attention :)

Comment: looks better *now* you get a +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

howabout a simple `cut`:

```
cut -c68- file
```

outputs:

```
sdmp.o.t.0.0.0.0.NewOrderExecutionOE.?.[cut for brevity]
```

same approach using `sed`

```
sed 's/^.\{67\}//' file
```

using `colrm`

```
$ colrm 1 67 < file
```

`perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/^.{67}//' file
```

Finally `awk` (can't beat @kent for brevity here)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="67 9999"}{print$2}' file
```

Comment: `sed 's/.*subject=[^.]*\.//'` maybe better?

Comment: just trying to show the `cut` approach using different tools. But yes, your `sed` is better but I wasn't aiming for that. BTW +1 to your awk!

Answer (score 1):

if there is only one `PROD.`, you don't have to split with period ".", you could:

```
awk -F'PROD.' '$0=$2' input
```

or

```
awk -F'PROD\\.' '$0=$2' input
```

however I guess your `PROD.foo.bar` could be dynamic, e.g. `TEST.foo.bar` or `DEV.foo.bar...`, in this case, you could take the `subject=`

```
awk -F'subject=[A-Z]+\\.' '$0=$2' input
```

you coud adjust `[A-Z]` if there could be other possibilities. grep with PCRE supported (e.g. gnu grep) could work too.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `sub`.

```
awk '{sub(/^[0-9][-0-9:. :)(Z]* subject=PROD./, ""); print;}'
```

This basically matches everything from "start of line" up to "subject=PROD." and replaces it with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

While you asked for awk **sed** may well be THE tool for the job:

```
sed -r 's/^.+ subject=PROD\.(.*)/\1/' file
```